# Get text occurances and edition info from Books API

Tags: java, android, google-books

Is there any way to get the page numbers where the search phrase was found? It's not involved into the JSON, so I thought I could get it through text mining, but I only get download links to acsm-files.

I know, that I can include them into a web view to download them in Android, but can I "read" them? Or any othe suggestions?

thanks!